# Route to https endpoint using Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, security, ssl, spring-cloud-gateway

We have requirement to conditionally route request to different REST endpoints.

The implementation is done using Spring Cloud Gateway and routing is working fine so far for testing purposed. But as we move in prod, there would be external endpoints with encrypted communication using TLS (https). To my understanding, the client would need to get certificate from trusted authority to expose HTTPS endpoint.

I am trying to understand steps/configuration that would be needed in Spring Cloud Gateway App to enable routing of data to clients (https)?